# Simplified version of the pattern

Tags: regex

I have construct a pattern, that match all words, that contain "word":

`[a-z0-9]+word[a-z0-9]+|word[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+word|word`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/n1pWuB/1

`[a-z0-9]`is not necessary - I just need to match all symbols of the words that contain "word".
The space - the word's separator.

Please help me to simplify this pattern.

Comment: Why not just separate on word boundaries and look for `word`?

Comment: @DaveNewton, sometimes a ```word``` may consist of more than one word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to use `[a-z0-9]`, you could match 0+ non whitespace characters `\S*` before and after `word`. If `\S` is too broad, you could also use a [character class](https://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to specify what you would allow to match or match 0+ word characters using `\w*`

```
\S*word\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q9vaAS/1)

Comment: @SharpUser That's precisely what I said in my comment (more or less--this regex won't handle punctuation properly).

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, I did.

Comment: @DaveNewton I suggested several options for the OP to determine a suitable match.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, you did. Which is why (a) my comment was directed to the OP, not to you, and (b) why I was confused that my comment was insufficient and why a regex that was less-restrictive was "exactly" what they were looking for, and (c) why splitting on whitespace handled the case they specifically called out in their reply to my comment. The question was incomplete in its details, and showed very little effort.

Comment: @DaveNewton, in this case, I use specially prepared text, cleared of unnecessary characters.

Comment: @DaveNewton Then it is my misunderstanding as the comment was added to the answer, therefore I sincerely apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @Thefourthbird No worries--wasn't upset or anything :)